# Updating with django-nonrel

Tags: django

I have successfully deployed my Django project on GAE, thanks to the wonderful django-nonrel project. But every time I make a change to the project locally, to reflect the change on the cloud, I need to do a

```
./manage.py deploy
```

Which essentially clones ALL the files and uploads them. Is there a way to "update" the project, by cloning only the changed files, or even by specifying the files explicitly?

thanks,

Yati

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that, because that's a SDK thing, not a django-nonrel one. Maybe you should ask for this [on their issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list).